# Wrapping a NonZeroUsize in a new type

Tags: rust

I have read that `Option<NonZeroUsize>` occupies exactly one word of memory, like `usize`.

I would like to combine this with the [new type idiom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html). I would like to define `struct Pos(NonZeroUsize)`, so that the compiler prevents me from confusing a `Pos` with any other `NonZeroUsize`, but without losing the compact representation.

Will `Option<Pos>` occupy exactly one word of memory?

Comment: You can check your hypothesis yourself using `mem::size_of`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=77383e32da0a522c15ae088d772932d9

Comment: While not *guaranteed* as Frxstrem's answer says, it's definitely intended for this "niche optimization" to look deeply into the structure, its designed so it works for more complicated things like `Vec`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, while the compiler is likely to be able to optimize the size of `Option<Pos>`, types without a `#[repr]` annotation have no guarantees about memory layout:

> [**The Default Representation**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-default-representation)
> Nominal types without a `repr` attribute have the default representation. Informally, this representation is also called the `rust` representation.
>
> There are no guarantees of data layout made by this representation.

However, you can specify `#[repr(transparent)]` to force `Pos` to have the same layout as its singular field:

```rust
#[repr(transparent)]
struct Pos(NonZeroUsize);
```

> [**The `transparent` Representation**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-transparent-representation)
> The transparent representation can only be used on a struct or an enum with a single variant that has:
>
> - a single field with non-zero size, and
> - any number of fields with size 0 and alignment 1 (e.g. PhantomData).
>
> Structs and enums with this representation have the same layout and ABI as the single non-zero sized field.

Then `Option<Pos>` will always have the same size as `NonZeroUsize`, per points 5 and 7 in this list:

> [**`Option` Representation**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/#representation)
> Rust guarantees to optimize the following types `T` such that `Option<T>` has the same size as `T`:
>
> 1. `Box<U>`
> 2. `&U`
> 3. `&mut U`
> 4. `fn`, `extern "C" fn`
> 5. `num::NonZero*`
> 6. `ptr::NonNull<U>`
> 7. `#[repr(transparent)]` struct around one of the types in this list.